# Azure Mobile Apps Server on .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, azure, mobile

What is with this stuff? As of today, there is no support to write a backend in C#/Net.

The [Repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server) is super old and does not contain anything but .NET Framework examples. The packages produced are obviously not NET 5 compatible, although this is not listed in the Nuget browser.

[This](https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps/) seems to be the current site, but the server example in ASP.NET is broken and even the quickstart documentation for the client code refers to a deployment of the NodeJs server.
You can get the server example to compile by rewiring some dependencies to the Datasync projects in the Repo, however I wasn't able to run it (probably due to my lacking knowledge of Azure configuration stuff).

Any news?

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.NET Framework SDK for Azure Mobile Apps**

Create an Azure Mobile Apps ASP.NET Framework backend

Download and initialize the SDK

select **Manage NuGet Packages...**., Install

```
  Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server
  Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Quickstart
  Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

#### Initialize the server project

Add Startup class
Include Microsoft SDK extensions

```
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Quickstart, Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Home,
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables,  Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity,
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication,
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications,
Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.CrossDomain,Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login
```

#### Publish the server project in Azure

Please follow the  **[ASP.NET Framework SDK for Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/howto/server/dotnet-framework#reference-documentation)** for reference.

Comment: Right, did that, but I'm looking for .NET 5 or at least a roadmap for migration as I'm in the decision process for a new project. Are there any C# alternatives, even commercial ones for mobile apps on Azure? I'm especially interested in DataSync.